# How can you prove that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow z}[\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x)]=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow z}f(y, z)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I want to prove that:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow z}[\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x)]=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow z}f(y, z)$$

As long as all the limits exist (and with no other restrictions or assumptions).

What I have done so far is:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow z}[\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x)] =L_1 \implies$$

$$(\forall \space \epsilon_1 > 0 \space \exists \space \delta_2 > 0:0<|x-z|<\delta_1 \implies |\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x) - L_1| < \epsilon_1)$$

$$\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x) =L_2 \implies (\forall \space \epsilon_2 > 0 \space \exists \space \delta_2 > 0:0<|y-x|<\delta_2 \implies |f(y,x) - L_2| < \epsilon_2)$$

My problem is that I'm struggling to find a $\delta > 0$ such that I can prove that $|y - z| < \delta \implies |x - z| < \delta_1 \space \land \space |y - x| < \delta_2$. Intuitively, I think $\delta=\min(\delta_1, \delta_2)$ would work so I did:

$$|y - z|=|(y - x) + (x - z)|$$

I would like to apply the triangle inequality and make it so that:

$$|y - z|\leq|y - x| + |x - z| < |y - x| + \delta_1 \implies |x - z| < \delta_1$$

Similarly with $\delta_2$. However, I don't believe this is a valid line of reasoning as the inequality from the triangle inequality does not guarantee that $|y - x| + |x - z| < \delta$ and thus, does not guarantee that substituting $|x-z| < \delta_1$ is true.

How can one choose a $\delta$ and prove that if $|y - z| < \delta \implies |x - z| < \delta_1 \space \land \space |y - x| < \delta_2$?

EDIT: Considering the counter example from Ryszard Szwarc it seems that continuity of $\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow z}f(y, z)$ is a sufficient condition for the equality to be true. It is also a necessary condition, as noted by Ryszard Szwarc, since if $g(x)=\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x)$ where discontinuous at $z$ then:

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow z}g(x)\neq g(z)$$
$$\implies \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow z}[\lim\limits_{y\rightarrow x}f(y, x)] \neq \lim\limits_{y\rightarrow z}f(y, z)$$

Comment: Denote $g(x)=\lim_{y\to x}f(y,x).$ Then the claim takes the form $\lim_{x\to z}g(x)=g(z),$ i.e. $g$ is continuous at the point $z.$ Perhaps it may help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc does this mean that continuity of $g$ at $z$ is a necessary condition for this to be true?

Comment: Yes, it is just a reformulation of your problem. See the answer below, where the function $f(y,x) $ is independent of $y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$f(y,x)=\begin{cases} 1 & x\neq 0\\ 0& x=0\end{cases}$$ For $z=0$ we have $$\lim_{y\to 0}f(y,0)=0,\ \  \lim_{x\to 0}[\lim_{y\to x}f(y,x)]= 1$$